# Adding QTimer creates local variable error

Tags: pyqgis

In QGIS v2.18 I am writing a processing script combining two of the default scripts found in the Processing Toolbox, ‘Random Extract’ and ‘Differential Privacy’.  I believe I need to add a timer to allow enough time for Random Extract to create a temporary layer before Differential privacy begins working on it.  Through my studying I have come up with the following code:

```
QTimer.singleShot(1000, refreshLayers)

def refreshLayers():
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

However, I get the following error: 
*“local variable 'refreshLayers' referenced before assignment See log for more details”.*

I take it the message is referring to the Log found in the GUI window... which is blank other than the error message.  Not sure if this helps but the variable name I am using is 'OUTPUT' and the actual temp layer name is called 'Extracted Points'.  Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Not sure why you use a timer here. Why don't you run the first algorithm, then take the result and provide it to the second algorithm like in https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#creating-scripts-and-running-them-from-the-toolbox? For your error, just put `QTimer.singleShot(1000, refreshLayers)` **after** the block `def refreshLayers():` It's where your error is coming from I think

Comment: Thx for quick reply Thomas. I am following that guide but I need to combine those scripts (and even add another), to automate the entire process hence adding the timer delay. Your suggestion worked by switching the lines of code.  It creates the layer now but then gives a new error "Algorithm instance has no attribute 'iface'".  I thought iface is like a global attribute? Ah, fun being a nubie.

Comment: It can if you add a python import in the first line of your script e.g `from qgis.utils import iface`. You can find real cases by searching the string `iface` in the existing Python processing scripts located in paths you get from `qgis.utils.plugin_paths`. It could help you boostrap your understanding of the processing scripts in general, by inspecting existing code.

Comment: Yea, tried that but still get same error. I'll continue to research and mark this question as answered since it dealt with the QTimer.